# Вывод массива значений jquery в div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть проблема! Нужно из массива значений вывести каждое значение в отдельный div
На данный момент у меня выводит весь массив в один div. Как их разделить?

```
    <div class="order_id"></div>
    <div class="table_number"></div>

    $.each(data,function(index,value) {
      var order_id = valu`введите сюда код`e.order_id;
      $(".order_id").append(order_id);
      var table_number= value.table_number;
      $(".table_number").append(table_number);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("<div></div>").text(JSON.stringify(table_number)).appendTo(".table_number");
```

Comment: Все отлично! Но есть вопрос выводит в таком виде: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]... Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: @DimRt `...JSON.stringify(table_number)...`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Удачи и не болей!)

Comment: @DimRt На здоровье. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.